# How to set focus to a TLFTextfield object

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been trying to understand why it will not work for me. Im working on the timeline in FLASH CS5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this thread http://www.gotoandlearnforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&p=125498 you can try

```
txt.textFlow.interactionManager.setFocus();
```