# How to set focus on TLFTextField

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, tlf

like the title said. How to set focus on TLFTextField on runtime?

I already do some research and find a few question answered in SO like this [How to set focus to a TLFTextfield object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193743/how-to-set-focus-to-a-tlftextfield-object)

And on few forum, they said to use this code

```
stage.focus = txt;
```

or

```
txt.stage.focus = txt;
```

or

```
txt.textFlow.interactionManager.setFocus();
```

But none works for me.. I'd try on simple project and still failed..

I need to show a `MovieClip` with a `TLFTextField` and focus on it.. So user can just type to edit the TLFTextfield.

my code:

```
public function TFLayer() {
    tf = new TLFTextField();
    tf.width = 400;
    tf.height = 30;
    tf.x = 300;
    tf.y = 300;
    tf.border = true;
    tf.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    tf.backgroundColor = 0xffffff;
    tf.text = "Lorem ipsum";
    addChild(tf);

    tf.textFlow.interactionManager.setFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given an editable `TLFTextField` named `tf`, you can enable focus with:

```
import flashx.textLayout.edit.EditManager;

tf.textFlow.interactionManager = new EditManager();
tf.textFlow.interactionManager.selectRange(0, 0);
tf.textFlow.interactionManager.setFocus();
```

Using this method, the text field is focused ready to receive input from the keyboard; however, the cursor will not blink.  Therefore, there's no visual indication of focus.

`TLFTextFields` are not optimal for user input.  Consider using `TextField` or `TextArea` instead.

Comment: I need verticalAlign which `TextField` lack of it... Add `tf.setSelection(tf.text.length, tf.text.length);` and the code is complete... Thanks for the help :)... it make me crazy for day...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jason Sturges, now I have the simplified answer. After testing his code, I decide to experiment further and it comes that I only need 2 lines of code to make this works..

```
    tf.textFlow.interactionManager.setFocus();
    tf.setSelection(tf.text.length, tf.text.length);.
```

there is no need to import `flashx.textLayout.edit.EditManager`. Weird enough, because `interactionManager` actually need `EditManager` to works.

But this code works fine for me. I compile it with FlashDevelop. I event didn't add `textLayout.swc` to my libs