# how to enable blink cursor in TLFTextFeild in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

`mc.textFlow.interactionManager.setFocus();//mc is a TLFTextField`
It successfully gives focus to mc, however the familiar blinking text cursor/beam does not appear in the TLFTextField. This makes you think it does not have focus, so how to set cursor.

[[How to set focus on TLFTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027595/how-to-set-focus-on-tlftextfield][1]) - Here i refered about focus set

Comment: check your interaction manager is EditManager

Comment: Thank You Gowtham, Myself find out, when i call interactionManager.setFocus() method that time my stage has focus instead of TLFTextFeild, that is the issue.Remove stage focus or set stage.focus=null, this gives blink cursor.[link](https://forums.adobe.com/message/966402#966402)